# Efficiently enumerating multinomials with constant sum - R

Tags: r, constraints, combinatorics, memory-efficient

Let's say I have an N-side dice with non-uniform probabilities for each side and I throw it M times. Now instead of observing the individual outcomes, we only observe the sum.

I have to code the likelihood where I have to sum over the multinomial likelihood components restricted to having that observed sum.

If N=3, M = 2 and the sum is 4, than it is clear that I have to sum over the two cases where one of the throws is 1 and the other 3 plus the case where both are 2.

I could also enumerate all possibilities, calculate the sum and restrict the calculation to the combinations with the sum I'm interested in, but clearly that becomes intractable quite quickly with increasing N and M.

So I am looking for an efficient approach to select the constant-sum combinations in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `RcppAlgos::compositionsGeneral()` which employs 'efficient algorithms for partitioning numbers under various constraints'.

```
library(RcppAlgos)

compositionsGeneral(3, 2, repetition = TRUE, target = 4)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    1
```

As @ThomasIsCoding has pointed out, this approach can fail with the message:

```
compositionsGeneral(3, 6, repetition = TRUE, target = 10)

Error: Currently, there is no composition algorithm for this case.
 Use permuteCount, permuteIter, permuteGeneral, permuteSample, or
 permuteRank instead.
```

So to deal with this, we can catch errors and fall back on `permuteGeneral()` with constraints in this event:

```
comps <- \(v, m, x) {
  tryCatch(
    compositionsGeneral(v,
                        m,
                        repetition = TRUE,
                        target = x),
    error = function(e)
      permuteGeneral(v,
                     m,
                     repetition = TRUE,
                     constraintFun = "sum",
                     comparisonFun = "==",
                     limitConstraints = x
      )
  )
}


comps(3, 6, 10)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    3    3
 [2,]    1    1    1    3    1    3
 [3,]    1    1    1    3    3    1
 [4,]    1    1    3    1    1    3
 [5,]    1    1    3    1    3    1
...
[85,]    2    2    1    1    2    2
[86,]    2    2    1    2    1    2
[87,]    2    2    1    2    2    1
[88,]    2    2    2    1    1    2
[89,]    2    2    2    1    2    1
[90,]    2    2    2    2    1    1
```

Note that the documentation includes the following about calculating permutations with contraints:

> Finding all combinations/permutations with constraints is optimized by
> organizing them in such a way that when constraintFun is applied, a
> partially monotonic sequence is produced. Combinations/permutations
> are added successively, until a particular combination exceeds the
> given constraint value for a given constraint/comparison function
> combo. After this point, we can safely skip several combinations
> knowing that they will exceed the given constraint value.

Comment: But there are three cases: 1-3, 3-1, and 2-2. No?

Comment: This is not my understanding. He/she said "the 2 cases where ... plus the case where....". And given the description of the problem, the order matter : {1,3} unordered is a more frequent outcome than {2, 2}.

Comment: Ah indeed - I misread it.  Thanks. Will edit.

Comment: Concise and efficient, +1! By the way, what if `target = 10` and `M = 6`? It seems giving errors.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding - see update - I guess it's not ideal but users are largely not going to know if the function can determine a solution algorithmically until they call it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the block partitions of the **partitions** package:

```r
> blockparts(rep(3, 2), 4)
          
[1,] 3 2 1
[2,] 1 2 3
```

If N=5 (number of sides), you throw the dice M=2 times, and you get the sum 4, there's a problem, the cases 4-0 and 0-4 are included:

```r
> blockparts(c(5, 5), 4)
              
[1,] 4 3 2 1 0
[2,] 0 1 2 3 4
```

Instead of filtering, you can do:

```r
> x <- c(1, 1) # minimal values
> y <- c(5, 5) # maximal values
> sweep(blockparts(y - x, 4 - sum(x)), 1L, x, "+")
          
[1,] 3 2 1
[2,] 1 2 3
```

(this method is given in the doc of the package)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom function in a recursive manner, like below

```
f <- function(S, M, N = 3) {
    if (M == 1) {
        if (S <= N && S > 0) {
            return(S)
        } else {
            return(NULL)
        }
    }
    unlist(
        lapply(1:min(S,N), \(k) {
            Map(`c`, k, f(S - k, M - 1))
        }),
        recursive = FALSE
    )
}
```

such that:

- `target = 4` and `M = 2`

```
> f(4, 2)
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 1
```

- `target = 5` and `M = 3`

```
> f(5, 3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 1

[[4]]
[1] 2 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 2 2 1

[[6]]
[1] 3 1 1
```

- `target = 10` and `M = 6`

```
> f(10, 6) 
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 3 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 1 1 3 1 3

[[5]]
[1] 1 1 1 3 2 2

[[6]]
[1] 1 1 1 3 3 1

[[7]]
[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3

[[8]]
[1] 1 1 2 1 3 2

[[9]]
[1] 1 1 2 2 1 3

[[10]]
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2

[[11]]
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 1

[[12]]
[1] 1 1 2 3 1 2

[[13]]
[1] 1 1 2 3 2 1

[[14]]
[1] 1 1 3 1 1 3

[[15]]
[1] 1 1 3 1 2 2

[[16]]
[1] 1 1 3 1 3 1

[[17]]
[1] 1 1 3 2 1 2

[[18]]
[1] 1 1 3 2 2 1

[[19]]
[1] 1 1 3 3 1 1

[[20]]
[1] 1 2 1 1 2 3

[[21]]
[1] 1 2 1 1 3 2

[[22]]
[1] 1 2 1 2 1 3

[[23]]
[1] 1 2 1 2 2 2

[[24]]
[1] 1 2 1 2 3 1

[[25]]
[1] 1 2 1 3 1 2

[[26]]
[1] 1 2 1 3 2 1

[[27]]
[1] 1 2 2 1 1 3

[[28]]
[1] 1 2 2 1 2 2

[[29]]
[1] 1 2 2 1 3 1

[[30]]
[1] 1 2 2 2 1 2

[[31]]
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 1

[[32]]
[1] 1 2 2 3 1 1

[[33]]
[1] 1 2 3 1 1 2

[[34]]
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1

[[35]]
[1] 1 2 3 2 1 1

[[36]]
[1] 1 3 1 1 1 3

[[37]]
[1] 1 3 1 1 2 2

[[38]]
[1] 1 3 1 1 3 1

[[39]]
[1] 1 3 1 2 1 2

[[40]]
[1] 1 3 1 2 2 1

[[41]]
[1] 1 3 1 3 1 1

[[42]]
[1] 1 3 2 1 1 2

[[43]]
[1] 1 3 2 1 2 1

[[44]]
[1] 1 3 2 2 1 1

[[45]]
[1] 1 3 3 1 1 1

[[46]]
[1] 2 1 1 1 2 3

[[47]]
[1] 2 1 1 1 3 2

[[48]]
[1] 2 1 1 2 1 3

[[49]]
[1] 2 1 1 2 2 2

[[50]]
[1] 2 1 1 2 3 1

[[51]]
[1] 2 1 1 3 1 2

[[52]]
[1] 2 1 1 3 2 1

[[53]]
[1] 2 1 2 1 1 3

[[54]]
[1] 2 1 2 1 2 2

[[55]]
[1] 2 1 2 1 3 1

[[56]]
[1] 2 1 2 2 1 2

[[57]]
[1] 2 1 2 2 2 1

[[58]]
[1] 2 1 2 3 1 1

[[59]]
[1] 2 1 3 1 1 2

[[60]]
[1] 2 1 3 1 2 1

[[61]]
[1] 2 1 3 2 1 1

[[62]]
[1] 2 2 1 1 1 3

[[63]]
[1] 2 2 1 1 2 2

[[64]]
[1] 2 2 1 1 3 1

[[65]]
[1] 2 2 1 2 1 2

[[66]]
[1] 2 2 1 2 2 1

[[67]]
[1] 2 2 1 3 1 1

[[68]]
[1] 2 2 2 1 1 2

[[69]]
[1] 2 2 2 1 2 1

[[70]]
[1] 2 2 2 2 1 1

[[71]]
[1] 2 2 3 1 1 1

[[72]]
[1] 2 3 1 1 1 2

[[73]]
[1] 2 3 1 1 2 1

[[74]]
[1] 2 3 1 2 1 1

[[75]]
[1] 2 3 2 1 1 1

[[76]]
[1] 3 1 1 1 1 3

[[77]]
[1] 3 1 1 1 2 2

[[78]]
[1] 3 1 1 1 3 1

[[79]]
[1] 3 1 1 2 1 2

[[80]]
[1] 3 1 1 2 2 1

[[81]]
[1] 3 1 1 3 1 1

[[82]]
[1] 3 1 2 1 1 2

[[83]]
[1] 3 1 2 1 2 1

[[84]]
[1] 3 1 2 2 1 1

[[85]]
[1] 3 1 3 1 1 1

[[86]]
[1] 3 2 1 1 1 2

[[87]]
[1] 3 2 1 1 2 1

[[88]]
[1] 3 2 1 2 1 1

[[89]]
[1] 3 2 2 1 1 1

[[90]]
[1] 3 3 1 1 1 1
```